# Attribute based access control and role based, online bookstore example

Tags: access-control

I am asked to answer a question that says:

> One online book-store wants to grand access to clients regarding their subscription. There are 3 types of subscriptions A , B and C. Customers get access in the subscription type they chose. Also if a book is not listed in the subscription list it's free for all and , every 15th of every month all books are free.
>
> 1. Describe with formal representation the above policy on ABAC.
> 2. How many roles does the RBAC model needs and which?

My question has to do with both. The attributes I have to define are {A,B,C,""}? Or did you define the date as an attribute as well{A,B,C,"",15}? In addition how many roles do I need in the RBAC model? A,B,C,NO,15? Or just a customer role as described in [this answer on Security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/111428/49923)?

Comment: This does not seem to be about cryptography...

Comment: You are right. i moved this to security:http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113287/attribute-based-access-control-and-role-based-online-bookstore-example . Feel free to post there.